# NFS error through LDAP configuration

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-14.04, openldap, nfs

I'm setting up a distributed system working with user accounts using LDAP and NFS4 in Ubuntu 14.04 OS. The thing is the client isn't mounting the FS on boot so I'm willing to use Autofs-LDAP in order to get home directories mounted when the user authenticates himself by LDAP.

To achieve that, I've set up the NFS server using NFSv4 and exporting in /etc/exports the home directories as follows:

```
/srv/nfs4/home    2001:470:736b:dfe::/64(ro,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,fsid=0)
```

This configuration is correct and from the client, I can mount "/home" using the mount command which contains the following along with other devices:

```
[2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/    /home   nfs auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=4,intr,actimeo=1800  0   0
```

My entries related to Automount within the LDAP server look like these(extracted from the creation file .ldif):

```
dn: ou=auto.home,dc=d,dc=ff,dc=es,dc=eu,dc=org
ou: auto.home
objectClass: top
objectClass: automountMap

dn: cn=nicu,ou=auto.home,dc=d,dc=ff,dc=es,dc=eu,dc=org
objectClass: automount
cn: nicu
automountInformation: -fstype=nfs,auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr    [2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu
```

If I type slapcat then, the entries appear in it.
I have followed both guides, [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutofsLDAP) and [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/AutoFSSetup), which have left me with the following configuration in the client:

/etc/default/autofs

```
#
# Define default options for autofs.
#
# MASTER_MAP_NAME - default map name for the master map.
#
MASTER_MAP_NAME="/etc/auto.master"
#
# TIMEOUT - set the default mount timeout (default 600).
#
TIMEOUT=300
#
# NEGATIVE_TIMEOUT - set the default negative timeout for
#            failed mount attempts (default 60).
#
#NEGATIVE_TIMEOUT=60
#
# MOUNT_WAIT - time to wait for a response from mount(8).
#          Setting this timeout can cause problems when
#          mount would otherwise wait for a server that
#          is temporarily unavailable, such as when it's
#          restarting. The defailt of waiting for mount(8)
#          usually results in a wait of around 3 minutes.
#
#MOUNT_WAIT=-1
#
# UMOUNT_WAIT - time to wait for a response from umount(8).
#
#UMOUNT_WAIT=12
#
# BROWSE_MODE - maps are browsable by default.
#
BROWSE_MODE="no"
#
# MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL - specify the default protocol used by
#                  mount.nfs(8). Since we can't identify
#                  the default automatically we need to
#                  set it in our configuration.
#
MOUNT_NFS_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL=4
#
# APPEND_OPTIONS - append to global options instead of replace.
#
#APPEND_OPTIONS="yes"
#
# LOGGING - set default log level "none", "verbose" or "debug"
#
LOGGING="debug"
#
# Define server URIs
#
# LDAP_URI - space seperated list of server uris of the form
#        <proto>://<server>[/] where <proto> can be ldap
#        or ldaps. The option can be given multiple times.
#        Map entries that include a server name override
#        this option.
#
#        This configuration option can also be used to
#        request autofs lookup SRV RRs for a domain of
#        the form <proto>:///[<domain dn>]. Note that a
#        trailing "/" is not allowed when using this form.
#        If the domain dn is not specified the dns domain
#        name (if any) is used to construct the domain dn
#        for the SRV RR lookup. The server list returned
#        from an SRV RR lookup is refreshed according to
#        the minimum ttl found in the SRV RR records or
#        after one hour, whichever is less.
#
LDAP_URI="ldap://nfsnis1.d.ff.es.eu.org"
#
# LDAP__TIMEOUT - timeout value for the synchronous API  calls
#         (default is LDAP library default).
#
#LDAP_TIMEOUT=-1
#
# LDAP_NETWORK_TIMEOUT - set the network response timeout (default 8).
#
#LDAP_NETWORK_TIMEOUT=8
#
# Define base dn for map dn lookup.
#
# SEARCH_BASE - base dn to use for searching for map search dn.
#       Multiple entries can be given and they are checked
#       in the order they occur here.
#
SEARCH_BASE="dc=d,dc=ff,dc=es,dc=eu,dc=org"
#
# Define the LDAP schema to used for lookups
#
# If no schema is set autofs will check each of the schemas
# below in the order given to try and locate an appropriate
# basdn for lookups. If you want to minimize the number of
# queries to the server set the values here.
#
#MAP_OBJECT_CLASS="nisMap"
#ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS="nisObject"
#MAP_ATTRIBUTE="nisMapName"
#ENTRY_ATTRIBUTE="cn"
#VALUE_ATTRIBUTE="nisMapEntry"
#
# Other common LDAP nameing
#
MAP_OBJECT_CLASS="automountMap"
ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS="automount"
MAP_ATTRIBUTE="ou"
ENTRY_ATTRIBUTE="cn"
VALUE_ATTRIBUTE="automountInformation"
#
#MAP_OBJECT_CLASS="automountMap"
#ENTRY_OBJECT_CLASS="automount"
#MAP_ATTRIBUTE="automountMapName"
#ENTRY_ATTRIBUTE="automountKey"
#VALUE_ATTRIBUTE="automountInformation"
#
# AUTH_CONF_FILE - set the default location for the SASL
#              authentication configuration file.
#
AUTH_CONF_FILE="/etc/autofs_ldap_auth.conf"
#
# MAP_HASH_TABLE_SIZE - set the map cache hash table size.
#           Should be a power of 2 with a ratio roughly
#           between 1:10 and 1:20 for each map.
#
#MAP_HASH_TABLE_SIZE=1024
#
# General global options
#
#OPTIONS=""
#
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

# pre_auth-client-config # passwd:         compat
passwd: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # group:          compat
group: files ldap
# pre_auth-client-config # shadow:         compat
shadow: files ldap

automount: files ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

# pre_auth-client-config # netgroup:       nis
netgroup: nis
```

/etc/auto.master

```
/home   ldap:ou=auto.home,dc=d,dc=ff,dc=es,dc=eu,dc=org
```

The account authentication client-server works fine but when the user is authenticated and is accessing to his home, the directory cannot be mounted from NFS server and these logs are shown within syslog:

```
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: Starting automounter version 5.0.7, master map /etc/auto.master
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: using kernel protocol version 5.02
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: lookup_nss_read_master: reading master file /etc/auto.master
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry /home
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: master_do_mount: mounting /home
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: automount_path_to_fifo: fifo name /var/run/autofs.fifo-home
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: lookup_nss_read_map: reading map ldap ldap:ou=auto.home,dc=d,dc=ff,dc=es,dc=eu,dc=org
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: parse_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: mounted indirect on /home with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
Apr 16 18:56:07 u automount[846]: st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /home
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: handle_packet: type = 3
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 1, name nicu, request pid 936
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: attempting to mount entry /home/nicu
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=nfs,auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr#011[2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=nfs,auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("[2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu") -> [2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=fstype=nfs,auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr, loc=[2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /home, mountpoint nicu, what [2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu, fstype nfs, options auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: mount_mount: mount(nfs): root=/home name=nicu what=[2001:470:736b:dff:5054:fff:fe0d:ff05]:/nicu, fstype=nfs, options=auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: mount_mount: mount(nfs): nfs options="auto,noatime,nolock,nfsvers=4,intr", nobind=0, nosymlink=0, ro=0
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: mount(nfs): no hosts available
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 1
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: handle_packet: type = 3
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: handle_packet_missing_indirect: token 2, name nicu, request pid 936
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 2
Apr 16 18:57:07 u automount[846]: failed to mount /home/nicu
```

As you can see, it looks like it can't get any NFS server but again, mount command is working. Any thoughts on what's going on here? Maybe there are some invalid options but they are the same in both  client's /etc/fstab and server LDAP entry. I don't know what I am missing here.

Thank you.